# Une nuance entre « attendre de qqn que » et « s'attendre à ce que qqn »

Tags: sens

> Vous ne pouvez pas **attendre des pacifistes qu**'ils nous obéissent.
>
> vs : Vous ne pouvez pas **vous attendre à ce que les pacifistes** nous obéissent.

Je me demande si ces locutions se traduisent toutes les deux par "expect someone to do something" sans une once de nuance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight difference:

> Vous ne pouvez pas attendre des pacifistes qu'ils nous obéissent.

means

> You can not expect of the pacifists to obey us

while

> Vous ne pouvez pas vous attendre à ce que les pacifistes nous obéissent.

can be translated as

> You can not expect that the pacifists will obey us.

In a nutshell, "attendre de" means "to expect something of someone/something", while "s'attendre à" means "to expect something"